# How to fix Jupyter consistent error when launching: "Could not open static file ' ' "

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

This didn't occur when I first started using Jupyter and not sure how this came about, but now whenever I launch Jupyter Notebook through my terminal or via Anaconda, I get a red error line saying "Could not open static file" and many yellow error lines related to static components. My Jupyter fails quite often now.

I've tried updating jupyter and changing the tornado version several times.

Simply installing "jupyter notebook"

I expect the code to run normally and terminal lines to be green.

[screenshot of terminal here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53AA8.png)

Comment: Are you using a stable version of Jupyter notebook? I am unsure.

Comment: as far as I know, yes? I've done conda update Jupyter a few times. Is there a way to do a hard reset of Jupyter or Anaconda?

Comment: perhaps since you have been updating conda and jupyter you might need to update jupyter one more time: conda update jupyter .... If that doesn't wokr you can always try to reinstall cleanly as per the website : https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-jupyter-using-anaconda-and-conda

Comment: Sorry I'm not of more help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried to update or reinstall jupyterlab but it said that some of the packages were missing. I tried to install those packages but failed as they appeared interdependent on each other in a circular fashion (A->B->C->A).

**I solved it by removing the Anaconda environment and recreating it**. Luckily, I had saved the environment file when it was working file. So used it to recreate the environment again.

```
conda env remove --name myenv

conda env create -f environment.yaml
```